# How can I generate a list of all my IAM roles and the services using those roles on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there a recommended tool to do this?

Is there a way to programmatically do this? If so, what would be the best approach for programmatically achieving this task?

Comment: You can use [SDKs and Programming Toolkits for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/). Pick the appropriate toolkit for your preferred language. Listing roles would use the `DescribeRoles()` command. You could look in the Trust Policy for roles to determine which services can assume the Role. Try it out, let us know if you have a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of what is actually being used you can use [AWS CloudWatch Insight](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html)  You will also need to have a [CloudTrail configured to send a log stream to CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs.html).

There are 2 downsides to this approach.   It only shows what roles are actually used.  And you need to have CloudTrail logging already enabled.

1. In the AWS Console go the CloudWatch -> Logs -> Insight.
2. In the "Select Log Group(s)" field select the CloudTrail stream you configured above.
3. Enter the below query

```
fields userAgent, requestParameters.roleArn
| filter eventName == "AssumeRole"
| stats count(*) by userAgent, requestParameters.roleArn
```

It will produce a list of services that are using which roles.
[image]

Note, that this query will include all AWS identities. To limit to just AWS Services like you asked use the following query that filters for AWS Services.

```
fields userAgent, requestParameters.roleArn
| filter eventName == "AssumeRole"
| filter userIdentity.type == "AWSService"
| stats count(*) by userAgent, requestParameters.roleArn
```

Further information on [analyzing logs with CloudWatch Insight.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html)

And if you want to get a list of roles and what services can use them here is a aws cli command that will probably get you close to what you want.

```
$ aws iam list-roles --query 'Roles[].[RoleName,AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service]' --output json
```